# Logout button not changing to login button in react-firebase single page site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, local-storage

This code worked the first time for login, but then when i logged out, it successfully did so but instead of changing the logout button to login again, after refreshing the page it just removed my name and pfp from the top of the navbar with the logout button still there, what changes should i make here to make it work?

here's a picture of the page before logout

[image: here's a picture of the page before logout]

here's a picture of the page after logout and refresh

[image: here's a picture of the page after logout and refresh]

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { auth, signInWithGoogle } from '../Firebase';

const Navbar = () => {

    // To get a state of addItems, use name of the file not the function
    const state = useSelector((state) => state.addItem);

    const logOut = async () => {
        await auth.signOut().then(console.log("signed out."));
        localStorage.clear(auth);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light py-3 shadow-sm">
                <div className="container">
                    <NavLink className="navbar-brand fw-bold fs-4" to="/">DUST</NavLink>
                    <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav mx-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className="nav-link active" aria-current="page" to="/">HOME</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/products">PRODUCTS</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/about">ABOUT</NavLink>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/contact">CONTACT</NavLink>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <div className="buttons">
                            {localStorage.getItem("name") === "" ? (
                                    <button className="btn btn-outline-dark ms-3" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
                                        <i className='fa fa-sign-in me-1'></i> LOGIN
                                    </button>
                                ) : (
                                    <>
                                        <div className='container'>
                                            <NavLink to="/cart" className="btn btn-outline-dark ms-2 me-5">
                                                <i className='fa fa-shopping-cart me-1'></i>
                                                {state?.length}
                                            </NavLink>
                                            <h4 className="lead">{localStorage.getItem("name")}</h4>
                                            <img src={localStorage.getItem("profilePic")} alt="Profile" className='img-fluid img-responsive rounded-circle ms-2' style={{ height:50, width:50 }} />
                                            <button className="btn btn-outline-dark ms-5" onClick={logOut}> {/*localstorage clear*/}
                                                <i className='fa fa-sign-out me-1'></i> LOGOUT 
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </>
                                )
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `localStorage.getItem("test") === ""` will always be false because if the key doesn't exist then `getItem()` returns `null`. Try:

```
// without === ""
localStorage.getItem("name") ? (...) : (...)
```

You can however read user's name directly from Firebase authentication:

```
auth.currentUser?.displayName
```